# how to run php code before closing the browser

Tags: php, ajax, browser

I would like to run a small php script before closing the browser. 
I don't know it's possible or not.
I am trying with this but when I refresh the webpage then also running the code

```
<body onbeforeunload="xajax_closeBrowser();" >
```

Its not necessary to run ajax , may be simple php code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Want to some updation in DataBase.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell if the browser is closing or the user is simply navigating away. `onbeforeunload` is run in both cases, as it indicates the current page context is being discarded for whatever reason. There is no event to catch browser termination.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).unload( function () { //ajax call });
```

The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page.

P.S Only for away navigation.No another way.